# Why I need C++ linkage for a template?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, extern

Sometimes I try to follow the logic of some rules, sometimes the logic of why things are happening the way they do defeats any law that I know of.

Typically a template it's described as something that lives only during the compilation phase and it's exactly equivalent to hand-writing some function `foo` for any given type `T` .

So why this code doesn't compile ( I'm using C++11 with `gcc` and `clang` at the moment but I don't think it's that relevant in this case ) ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
extern "C" {
template <typename T>
T foo(T t)
{
    return t;
}
}
int main()
{
    uint32_t a = 42;
    std::cout << foo(a) << '\n';
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the thing that defeats all the logic is that the complain is about the linkage, and the implicit message is that this code doesn't generate a function, it generates something else that after compilation it's not suitable for a C style linkage.

What is the technical reason why this code doesn't compile ?

Comment: @crashmstr I don't know about what you tried but `extern "C"` affects the linking phase, not really about what "works or not", that's what the standard says about `extern`, also the code inside `extern` it's still being compiled with a C++ compiler .

Comment: Related to [template External Linkage ?can anyone Explain this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341055/template-external-linkage-can-anyone-explain-this)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's look at this from a simple perspective. At the very least, using `extern "C"` will remove the C++ name mangling. So, we then have your template, and we'll instantiate it twice.

```
int foo(int val);
float foo(float val);
```

Under C's naming rules, these are required to have the same name `foo` from the perspective of the linker. If they have the same name though, we can't distinguish between them, and we'll have an error.

Under C++, the rules for how names are mangled is implementation defined. So C++ compilers will apply a name mangling to these two functions to differentiate them. Perhaps we'll call them `foo_int` and `foo_float`.

Because C++ can do this, we have no issues. But `extern "C"` requires the compiler to apply the C naming rules.

Comment: I don't know if this is a smart or dumb thing coming from who designed this feature in the language ... I basically have to hand-code all the variation of T ?

Comment: If you want the functions to be callable by C code, then yeah. A caller compiled with a C compiler wouldn't know how to call a name mangled function.

Comment: @user2485710 How would you expect to call the instantiations from C? If you don't intend to do that, then why are you using `extern "C"`?

Comment: It's a bit harsh calling the absence of template metaprogramming in C a "dumb" thing; it was the young and simple predecessor to C++ so naturally it will be lacking in features.  You may be able to solve your problem with C macros if you are so intent on `extern "C"`.

Comment: @Sneftel well people keep saying that the average compiler is smarter then the average programmer, that any modern compiler can do interesting things with an AST, so I was hoping for some auto-magic from the compiler for free.

Comment: You're hoping for some C++-specific auto-magic from the C compiler that this code is intended to interoperate with? Despite it not being a C++ compiler?

Comment: @Aggieboy the "dumb" part for me is the fact that this `extern` block is going to be compiled by a C++ compiler anyway, so why you can't use it to its full powers ?

Comment: @user2485710: Because it's supposed to emit code that you could call from another vendor's C compiler.

Comment: @Sneftel which part is not going to be compiled by a C++ compiler ?

Comment: @user2485710: I'm becoming slightly confused because of your remarks. Could you tell me what you believe the point of `extern "C"` is?

Comment: Any code which is intended to take advantage of `extern "C"` is, by definition, not being compiled by a C++ compiler. If you're using it with a C++ compiler, you don't need `extern "C"`.

Comment: Okay there seems to be a misunderstanding. The C++ compiler does do the automagic whenever you can, but by saying `extern "C"` you are explicitly saying `DO NOT USE AUTOMAGIC`.  You are chopping the hands off of a novelist and expecting him to keep producing novels...

Comment: @Sneftel `extern "C"` it's C++ syntax, and `extern "C"` is about linkage, what is the problem with having a C++ compiler doing that kind of work ? Why a C++ compiler shouldn't compile code inside an `extern` block ?

Comment: @sharth I know what the point is, I wish we had a better compile-time feature set .

Comment: The C++ compiler has no idea what the C compiler would use its templates for, and no way to produce code for them. This is a fundamental fact of how linkers work, and how C compilers work. It is not something that a "smarter" C++ compiler could do, and your complaining about C++ not being able to do it strongly suggests that you don't really know what `extern "C"` is for.

Comment: @Sneftel you are right, but I was thinking "backwards", one of the biggest negative of the templates is that they can't be packed in a library - right ? - so you need to write them in headers, imagine to translate the biggest weakness of the templates into a big advantage starting from the assumption that the C code that is using your template it's not invoking it from a library - because templates exist only in source code - and so you can tune and links things as you like;

Comment: after all it's what happens in C++ too, you can probably even overcome the limit of the C style name mangling with some hashing technique or something that packs any name in a single identifier . I guess that my point is : you don't need linkage rules with templates or rules that are so limited and stricts .

Comment: @user2485710 Exactly. Templates require the C++ compiler to be involved *at the point of instantiation*. If you're using `extern "C"`, then at that point, the C++ compiler isn't even running.

Comment: @user2485710 Incidentally, read up on the failed `export` keyword, which would have allowed uninstantiated templates to go into libraries. One of the main reasons that failed was because it wouldn't have been compatible with linkers intended for C code.

Comment: @user2485710 instead of "having to handcode stuff" you could just stop writing `extern "C"`.  The function is not callable from C either way. C does not have templates.

Answer (score 3):

"linkage" is a slightly misleading term. The main thing that `extern "C"` changes is name mangling. That is, it produces symbol names in the object files that are compatible with the sort of symbols that equivalent C code would produce. That way it can *link* with C object code.... but it's a different sort of thing than specifying `static` or `extern` linkage.

But templates don't have a C equivalent, and name mangling is used to make sure that different instantiations of a given templated function result in different symbol names (so that the linker knows which one to use in a given place).

So there's no way to give templates C linkage; you're asking the compiler to do two fundamentally incompatible things.

Comment: I agree, linkage is really really misleading, it also sound like a repetition when you use `extern` which is already about linkage in its own entirety and it doesn't really helps you in locating a specific error on a specific line or semantic.

Comment: Well, it still *is* linkage. It's a *kind* of extern linkage. There is, of course, no reason to declare something as having C-style mangling if you don't intend to give it extern linkage.

Comment: You can always wrap C++ name mangled stuff in C to avoid the linkage problem.  The indirect calls should be optimized away.

Comment: This is called *language linkage*, it's quite separate to *linkage* (despite the fact that the keyword `extern` comes in both cases).

Answer (score 0):

Well other answers have explained why it doesn't work from the C++ side.

From the C side there are work-rounds but they are not portable.

You can simply not use the `extern "C"` keyword, create name-mangled functions and then in the C code link to the actual mangled names.

To make that easier you could also use GCC's `abi::__cxa_demangle()` function combined with a look-up table so you don't need to know what the mangled function names are (just their demangled signature).

But it all a bit of a bodge really.

Of course if you only call the template functions from C code, they'll never get instantiated to begin with. So you would need to make sure they get called in the C++ code to make sure they're present in the object file.